# Como adicionar valor a um input quando apertar em um link com jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

Estou tendo o seguinte problema: não estou conseguindo setar o valor em um `input` quando ele está dentro de uma `function`. Exemplo:

```
$(document).on('click',".edita_cliente", function(){
    var id = $(".seq").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/lista_clientes.php?service=2&id=' + id,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#content").load('cadastra_cliente.php');
                $("#nome_cad").val(data[0].Nome);
            }, 700);
        }
    });
});
```

> Esta função, quando eu clico no botão, ele fecha o modal, carrega a
>   página. Mas ele não está colocando o valor no `input`. Testei de outras
>   formas, e percebi que ele não seta valor algum no `input` quando está
>   dentro de uma `function`. Alguém sabe me explicar porquê?
>
> Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa fazer um *callback* no `.load` para poder inserir o valor no `input` que será carregado. Esse `setTimeout` é totalmente desnecessário. Veja:

```
$(document).on('click',".edita_cliente", function(){
   var id = $(".seq").val();
   $.ajax({
      url: 'php/lista_clientes.php?service=2&id=' + id,
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
         $("#content").load('cadastra_cliente.php', function(){
            $("#nome_cad").val(data[0].Nome);
         });
      }
   });
});
```

Após o *callback*, o elemento estará devidamente carregado no `.load` e poderá ser usado. Da forma que está fazendo, o código passa direto do `.load` sem esperar o retorno dele.

Comment: Eu estava colocando este delay, devido ao tempo que ele tem para fechar o MODAL. Mas dessa forma funcionou.
Obrigado (novamente)!

Comment: @JoaoPedro Estamos aí! Dei +1 na sua pergunta tb. Abs!